# How do I record the email address of a user that clicks a link in an email?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web-applications, webforms

So I am sending my clients an email asking their level of satisfaction with my services. I want to record their answers in a database for analysis.
There are two buttons: thumbs up, thumbs down.
Both buttons take the user to a different webform in a web application.
Both webforms look identical (they just say thank you). But in the page load of the two different webforms, it will insert into my database if the user visited the thumbs up link, or the thumbs down link.
I want to be able to record which email address clicked on the link in my database as well.
Does anyone know how to do that?

This is the table i'm inserting into:

```
CREATE TABLE emails(
  ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  Cust nvarchar(max) not null,
  Rating nvarchar(max) not null,
  Points int not null,
  UpdateDate Datetime not null,
  UpdateUser nvarchar(max)  --This is the field I want to record the email address in!
  );
```

Comment: You would have to add a **GET** parameter to the webform link, with the email address of the intended destination. Yes, this provides inherit security risks of not being able to securely identify the user, so you could also generate secret tokens to include with the request. However, due to how Email works, it may always be spoofed.

Comment: Most createors of spam services know how to do that. Feel free to find and contact one. I'm sure searching for contacts ( "Does anyone know how to do that?") is off-topic on SO.

Comment: I'm not sure why people are downvoting the question, so if you feel like downvoting please leave her an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to add a **GET** parameter to the webform link, with the email address of the intended destination. Yes, this provides inherit security risks of not being able to securely identify the user, so you could also generate secret tokens to include with the request. However, due to how Email works, it may always be spoofed.

I.e.

http://contoso.com/Email/Subscription/?action=thumbsdown&email=barbara@contoso.com&token=7A8E1A6B-13F9-4292-BFB3-9D199E7FB96D

http://contoso.com/Email/Subscription/?action=thumbsup&email=barbara@contoso.com&token=7A8E1A6B-13F9-4292-BFB3-9D199E7FB96D

Alternatively, if you want to help provide basic security, make it an **HTTPS** request.

https://contoso.com/Email/Subscription/?action=thumbsdown&email=barbara@contoso.com&token=7A8E1A6B-13F9-4292-BFB3-9D199E7FB96D

https://contoso.com/Email/Subscription/?action=thumbsup&email=barbara@contoso.com&token=7A8E1A6B-13F9-4292-BFB3-9D199E7FB96D